# extract inline schema WSDL stylesheet xsom

Tags: java, xslt, wsdl

I want to extract inline schema from a WSDL file. But, I don't know how to perform XSL transformation for that. Any help on creating such a stylesheet would be great.

thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

This one is working for me:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match='text()' />

<xsl:template match="//s:schema">
    <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
</xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It assumes your inline schema uses the http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema namespace.

Comment: // set up XSLT
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer t;
try {
   t = tf.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("wsdl2xsd.xsl")));
   ContentHandler xsomHandler = parser.getParserHandler();

   // run the transformation and feed the result to XSOM
   t.transform(  new StreamSource(new File("BankLoanProcessArtifacts.wsdl")),  new SAXResult(xsomHandler));

Comment: Does it also work for BPEL WSDL..I am getting the following exception  com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformwhen I try to extract this schema using the above XSOM parser and your style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do when the wsdl contains more than one schema-elements: 
Use xsd-split.xslt from 
https://gist.github.com/ebratb/3819949
to to split the *.wsdl file into several *.xsd files.

You can use the maven plugin to run the 2.0 xslt with Saxon ( see http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/examples/transform-saxon.html )

Then write a small schema file that just imports those generated *.xsd files plus the official definition of the soap envelope.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"       elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://your.company.com/dummy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">                      
   <xsd:import namespace="http://<target namespace of the first xsd file>"  schemaLocation="file:///path/to/first.xsd"  />
   <xsd:import namespace="http://<target namespace of the second xsd file>" schemaLocation="file:///path/to/second.xsd"  />
    ...

   <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
</xsd:schema>
```

When using a custom Resource Resolver, the schemaLocation attributes are not needed.